# Deleting the content of any cell containing certain string

Tags: excel, replace, google-sheets, find, spreadsheet

I'm looking to delete the content of **any** cell containing a certain string of text. For example there could be cells of `Text1-XXX`, `Text2-XXX`, or `Text3-XXX`, and I would like to find any cell containing `XXX` and delete the contents of that cell. In this example that would have meant deleting the contents of three cells. I know you can find and replace, not enter anything in the replace, but that would still leave the "prefix" of the cell, in the example above, the `Text1`, `Text2`, and `Text3`.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about Excel, is that the case?

Comment: sure, we're using google sheets or excel, have access to both

Comment: You never mention that it's a spreadsheet is why I ask. LibreOffice Calc allows searching by regex, this might be a solution to remove the prefix with the search term but I am not familiar enough with Calc's find/replace to say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

In a google spreadsheet you can use 'find and replace'.
Tick the 'search with regular expression' box and enter in the search/find box

```
^(.+)XXX
```

and replace with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

**Without code:**

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to open the Find and Replace dialog box and then select either replace in in worksheet or workbook and surround your string to find with wildcards, then select nothing as replace value and click replace all. Note you can choose ignore case as well.

[image: Find and replace]

**With code:**

Use [`Range.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-replace-method-excel) with wildcard to partial match string so can replace entire string. Note also, use `UsedRange` to efficiently only replace in populated range. Change sheet name and `What` search string as required.

```
 Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Replace What:="*XXX*", Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
```

**Note:**

This is more efficient in Excel than using a regex.

Comment: Did you give this a try?